# How to hide BCC field in SENT email Outlook 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, bcc

I have a macro coded to a rule that autoforwards all incoming and sent emails to a private email address in the BCC field (any auto BCC rule is disabled at the server level.) With the help of the board here, the macro works flawlessly, and for all intents and purposes is invisible.

However, if you open the SENT message in the SENT FOLDER, the BCC field is visible to all for the world to see. I have learned this is a "feature" in Outlook, apparently since 2003.

Is there a way to suppress the visibility of the BCC field when viewing the SENT email?

Or is there a way one can set the display options of an individual folder NOT to display a BCC - EVER?

Thank you for any assistance.

My code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

      Dim objRecip As Recipient
      Dim strMsg As String
      Dim res As Integer
      Dim strBcc As String
      Dim answer
      Dim oAtt
      Dim strProc1 As String

On Error GoTo Application_ItemSend_Error

strBcc = "myprivateemail@gmail.com"

Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
objRecip.Type = olBCC

If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
    strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
    "Do you want still to send the message?"
    res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
    "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
    If res = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If

Set objRecip = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

Application_ItemSend_Error:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") " & "Error on 
Line " & Erl & " in procedure Application_ItemSend of VBA Document
ThisOutlookSession"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove BCC recipients in the Sent Items folder, listen for the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder, loop through all recipients in the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and delete recipients with `Recipient.Type = olBCC`.

Answer (score 0):

> "the BCC field is visible to all for the world to see"

Well, if anyone in the world can view your own sent folder, then this is the case. Otherwise the BCC field is not part of the email, recipients do not receive it. The goal of the feature is to have the ability to recall your own BCC messages, so you do not forget that you have sent them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim olRec As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Address$

    Address = "Om3r@blala.com"

    Set olRec = Item.Recipients.Add(Address)
    olRec.Type = olBCC
    olRec.Resolve
End Sub
```